# how to write "2023-9-15 00:00:00" by R

Tags: r

I am new for R, now I want to write a time like "2023-09-15 00:00:00", so I write the code

```
time1<- as.POSIXct("2013-9-15 00:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
print(time1) # [1] "2013-09-15 CST"
```

but it's not run. I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Hi zhh! I think it's because you're doing it at midnight. Why not just use the input string as is if you want the input to be the same as the output?

Comment: The `print()` function makes values look "pretty" before printing. That means if you have something that looks more like a date value than a date time value (because it has a time of midnight) the print will just show the value as a date. If you want to be specific how date time values are converted into strings, then use functions like `strftime` or `format` for more control: `strftime(time1, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")` But you cannot change the default "pretty" formatting of date times values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time1 <- as.POSIXct("2013-9-15 00:00:00")
time2 <- format(time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
print(time2)
```